# How can I run multiple stage of Gitlab CI at the some time without them interefering(because of port sharing) each other

Tags: docker, port, ros, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using the gitlab CI to run the tests on my project using ROS. All the stage of the CI run inside a docker image.

I have 2 stages, `integration_tests` and `unit_tests`. Both stages use the same ROS topics.  When the 2 stages run simultaneously on my machine, they interfere with each other. For example, during the running of `unit_test` I publish on topic `/abc` the message hello but integration_tests is listening on the same topic and read the message that make the test fails.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to tell the gitlab-runner to start the docker for the CI stages in an isolated mode so the network activity does not interfere between docker images?